# why is relative positioned element starting from top corner of window?

Tags: html, css

I am quite confused with this `relative and absolute` positioning when the parent or grand parent has a position values. can someone clear me out these two cases:

**Case 1**:

- grandparent - absolute
- parent - relative
- child - absolute

**Case 2:**

- grandparent - absolute
- parent - relative
- child - absolute

but here parent is independent of grandparent, like below:

```
<div class="grand-parent">

</div>

<div class="parent">
     <div class="child">

     </div> 
 </div>
```

Below is a fiddle which i have worked on:
https://jsfiddle.net/4KUWc/32/

Questions:

- I don't see any difference between the two cases above. Should the
  case 2, parent div not start after grand parent? Why is it taking
  (0,0)
- If relative has a parent of absolute, will it behave accordingly to
  the absolute parent or is not dependent on it.
- Can we have a relative children with absolute as parent?

Comment: Shane, cases 1 and 2 are identical. Are you sure that's what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `position:absolute`

...elements have their *relational positioning attributes* (i.e. `top`, `bottom`, `right`,...) calculated from their ***closest ancestor with a `position` value other than `static`*** (which is default). If no such ancestor exists, `<body>` will be used.

### `position:fixed`

...elements have their *relational positioning attributes* calculated from their ***closest viewport*** (by default: `<body>`, but a 3d transformed element acts as viewport for its children - see [Unfixing fixed elements with transforms](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/)).

Both of the above place the element, including all its children, *out of the content flow* of their parent. All subsequent elements in DOM will act like this element and its children do not exist in DOM.

### `position:relative`

...elements have their *relational positioning attributes* calculated from **the position they would normally occupy** in their parents content flow if no relational positioning attribute was applied. Unlike `fixed` and `absolute`, `relative` position ***does not*** place the element out of its parent contents flow.

Comment: According to your answer, both the absolute position and relative position impact lies on parent. If there is a parent div, both the div (may be absolute or relative), will follow its parent.

Comment: That is correct. However, please note that parent > child relations are not *declarative* in DOM. You can't declare something from one branch as a grand-child of another branch. It actually has to be in DOM under its parent to be a child of its parent.

Comment: Thanks, Cool, if in that case what does relative position do that absolute is not doing. Both are following their parents flow?

Comment: In both cases `.child` is calculated from `.parent` (you move parent, you move child). But in case 1 `.parent` is outside of document flow, because it's inside grand-parent (which is absolute) and in case 2 it's inside document flow. If any content was placed in `.parent` other than `.child` it would influence the document flow (would push siblings of `.parent` down).

Comment: Thanks for your time, but This is confusing, If my parent is absolute, my relative child is still going to follow parent and vice-versa. what makes relative position so special when inside a absolute parent?.... thanks again...

Comment: @Shane. An `absolute` element creates a new flow of their own, for its children. That flow acts pretty much the same as the normal one. Those children can be part of the absolute flow or taken out into a new, separate, absolute positioned flow.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, there is no magic happening. Just understand how each position work. Here's shortest summary I can think of:

- All elements **by default** have `position: static` , which means they will stack on each other (or inside each other if they're nested).
- If an element has `display: none` or has `width: 0px` and `height: 0px` then it will not take space, so other elements will just be rendered as the hidden element never existed.
- The CSS attributes `top` + `bottom` + `right` + `left` + `z-index` are ignored if the element position is static (the default). To work correctly, the element must be positioned relative, absolute, or fixed.
- `static` and `relative` are alike, except that `relative` may consider the attributes `top` + `bottom` + `right` + `left` + `z-index`.
- `relative` is positioned relative to its parent position.
- Element with position `absolute` or `fixed` are alike, with one difference: `absolute` will be positioned relatively to the **body**, while `fixed` will be positioned relatively the **window** (note @AndreiGheorghiu's answer about `fixed` position and 3D transform).
- `absolute` element will be relative to the nearest **parent** with position other than `static`. If all its parents are static, it will be relative to the **body**.

Comment: Please note "relative is positioned relative to its parent position" is simply false. It is positioned relative to where it would be positioned in DOM normally. Also `absolute` is positioned relative to closest ancestor with non `static` position, not necessarily to `window`. I believe your answer adds confusion over some areas which are difficult to understand for new-comers. Currently, last 3 points are all false, incomplete or misleading.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you've just repharsed that sentence. Anyway, here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tuhzask7/)

Comment: ***1)*** ***`absolute` element will be relative to nearest with position `relative`***? False: Think of parents with position `absolute` or `fixed`. ***2)*** ***`fixed` is positioned relative to the `window`***. False: 3d transform an element and give `position:fixed` to its children.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu About **absolute**, yes you're and I know it I just forgot to point it out. About **fixed**, you're right, first I knew about this! Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm only trying to make it less confusing for people who are just starting, like OP. I welcome your efforts, but they need to be *correct*. Cheers!